# nagios nrpe-server not working on Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nagios, nrpe

I am trying to deploy a container with nrpe. This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
nrpe-server:
    image: binfalse/nrpe-server:full
    container_name: dr_nrpe_server
    ports:
        - "5666:5666"
    volumes:
        - $nrpe_cfg_volume
        - $nrpe_plugins_volume
    environment:
        SSL: "no"
        PORT: 5666
        ALLOWEDHOSTS: "192.168.1.34"
    logging:
        driver: syslog
        options:
            tag: docker/nrpe-server
```

I am trying to do a `docker-compose up` on my Windows 10 Bash (Ubuntu), but I get the following error:

```
Creating dr_nrpe_server ... error                                                                                               

ERROR: for dr_nrpe_server  Cannot start service nrpe-server: failed to initialize logging driver: Unix syslog delivery error    

ERROR: for nrpe-server  Cannot start service nrpe-server: failed to initialize logging driver: Unix syslog delivery error       
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this definition for docker-compose:

```
nrpe-server:
    image: binfalse/nrpe-server:full
    container_name: dr_nrpe_server
    ports:
        - "5666:5666"
    volumes:
        - $nrpe_cfg_volume
        - $nrpe_plugins_volume
    environment:
        SSL: "no"
        PORT: 5666
        ALLOWEDHOSTS: "192.168.1.34"
    logging:
        options:
            tag: docker/nrpe-server
```

I removed line with logging driver. Your Docker will use your default setting for that.